# Is it possible to vary the width of each bar independently with ggplot2::geom_bar() with a continuous x-axis variable?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using ggplot2::geom_bar() to plot time series for temporally-binned data (on a geological timescale --- so these are stratigraphic time bins). I want to use a continuous x-axis variable so that I can display a geological timescale underneath.

Ideally, I would want each bar in the geom_bar plot to match the width of the appropriate time bin (these vary substantially in duration). As far as I can tell, however, this doesn't seem to be possible. Are there any clever tricks for accomplishing this?

Here is an example of a plot with fixed widths of each bar. I want each bar to expand to line up with the boundaries of each bin (Cm, Mst, etc.), such that there is no space between any of the bars, but they have different widths.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this using the `geom_col()` or `geom_bar()` functions. However, the type of chart you intend to use can be achieved with `geom_rec()`. To do this, you need to calculate the width of each bar by setting a starting and endpoint on the x-axis. I demonstrated this with some dummy data below. You also find some examples [here](https://r-graph-gallery.com/81-barplot-with-variable-width.html).

```r
library(tidyverse)

tibble(group= c("a", "b", "c"),
       y= c(2, 5, 10),
       xstart= c(0, 5, 8),
       xend= c(5, 8, 17)) |>
  ggplot()+
  geom_rect(aes(ymin= 0, ymax= y,
                xmin= xstart, xmax= xend,
                fill= group))
```

[image]